# when do I use Mono.flatMapIterable vs Mono.flapMapMany?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

New to reactor, trying to understand `Mono.flatMapMany` and `Mono.flatMapIterable` as often dealing with Mono's of an Object containing a collection.

Whats the difference between:

```
        Mono.just(List.of("one", "two", "three")).log().flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable).subscribe(System.out::println);
        Mono.just(List.of("one", "two", "three")).log().flatMapIterable(l -> l).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

When do I use each method?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Mono#flatMapMany` is a generic, one-to-many operator.
`Mono#flatMapIterable` is a special operator to "flatten" the item represented as `Iterable<T>` into a reactive stream of `T`.

Use `Mono#flatMapIterable` where possible (mapper can return Iterable) because it is optimized, use `Mono#flatMapMany` when your mapper returns a `Publisher` of items.

Comment: thanks, what confuses me is what to put inside a flatMapIterable call, is it the equivalent of (if flatMapIterable allowed this)

`Mono.just(List.of("one", "two", "three")).log().flatMapIterable().map(item -> doSomething(item).subscribe(System.out::println);`

Comment: a common example: `users.flatMapIterable(user -> user.getFavouriteAnimals())`